# kustomization namespace overwrite doesn't work for me

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces, kustomize

My k8s YAML manifests are organized like this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── base
│   │   └── kustomization.yaml
|   |   └── my-configmap.yaml
|   |   └── my-namespace.yaml
|   |   └── my-deploy.yaml  
|   |   └── my-svc.yaml  
│   ├── overlay
│       └── kustomization.yaml
        └── new-namespace.yaml
```

**=== The "base" ===**

The `app/base/kustomization.yaml` is:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - my-configmap.yaml
  - my-deploy.yaml
  - my-namespace.yaml
  - my-svc.yaml
```

In each YAML manifest inside `base/` directory, the `namespace` field is specified. For example `my-service.yaml` specified namespace `my-ns`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: my-svc
  name: my-svc
  namespace: my-ns
spec:
```

**=== The "Overlay" ===**

I would like to overwrite namespace of my objects using overlay.

The `app/overlay/kustomization.yaml` is:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - ../base
  - new-namespace.yaml
buildMetadata:
  - managedByLabel
transformers:
  - |-
    apiVersion: builtin
    kind: NamespaceTransformer
    metadata:
      name: namespace-transformer
    namespace: xii
    setRoleBindingSubjects: allServiceAccounts
```

That `app/overlay/new-namespace.yaml` is:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: xii
```

**==== Result ====**

Then, under path `app/overlay/`, I run command `kustomize build . | cat`, the output shows me all the namespace of my YAML manifests are still use the original one defined in "**base**" instead of being overwritten by **overlay** value `xii`.

Why? Do I misunderstand the behaviour of Kustomization namespace transformer?

**I also tried a simpler approach:**

I also tried removing the `transformers` completely, instead, simply use `namespace: xii` in **overlay's** `kustomizationl.yaml` like below:

```
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
resources:
  - ../base
  - new-namespace.yaml
buildMetadata:
  - managedByLabel
namespace: xii
```

When build it, I get error:

```
Error: namespace transformation produces ID conflict: [{"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Namespace","metadata":{"annotations":{"config.kubernetes.io/origin":"path: ../base/my-namespace.yaml\n","internal.config.kubernetes.io/previousKinds":"Namespace","internal.config.kubernetes.io/previousNames":"my-ns","internal.config.kubernetes.io/previousNamespaces":"_non_namespaceable_"},"name":"xii"}} {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Namespace","metadata":{"annotations":{"config.kubernetes.io/origin":"path: new-namespace.yaml\n"},"name":"xii"}}]
```

Comment: @ user842225 Let me know whether the shared info was helpful. I am happy to assist if you have any further queries. If the answer was helpful, What should I do [when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [git repository](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/3142)

The interaction between the namespace override in the kustomization is the reason why you are receiving the error.The namespace resources themselves as well as yaml’s

Everything functions as intended if you modify the components to standard Kustomizations and include them as resources in overlays/local/kustomization.yaml:

**For future reference** :

Refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/3156) and See [namespaceTransformer spec](https://kubectl.docs.kubernetes.io/references/kustomize/builtins/#_namespacetransformer):

Comment: Refer to this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173823)  regarding your issue

Comment: Hi Sai, thank you for your answer. I am very interested in the 1st link you provided, I mean the "git repository" one. I read through but still not quite sure if I understand correctly. Does it mean in my case my "base" is rendered, then merge with my "overlay", both have namespace resources thus creates the conflicts?? But I don't get even I have two namespace objects (one in base, one in overlay) they are different names, why kustomize still feel they conflicts, it would be nice if you could elaborate it though the links are great source to read too. Thanks!

Comment: I also wonder in my case do I have "component" since your 1st link is talking about that?? I suppose "base" and "overlay" are not component.

Comment: Refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/880) and this [doc](https://imixs.github.io/imixs-cloud/doc/KUSTOMIZE.html#overwriting-settings) may be helpful to understanding and resolving  your issue

Comment: Let me know whether the shared info was helpful. If the answer was helpful, What should I do [when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: I checked all your links.  Thanks.