How to exclude a resource when using namespace in kustomization.yaml?
Kustomize thinks that runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1 ExtensionConfig is namespaced. But it is not.
How to make kustomize not add namespace: ... to metadata of these resources?
Example, to reproduce:
extensionconfig.yaml
apiVersion: runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ExtensionConfig
metadata:
  name: my-extensionconfig

kustomization.yaml
resources:
- extensionconfig.yaml

namespace: foooo

output:
❯ kubectl kustomize  .
apiVersion: runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ExtensionConfig
metadata:
  name: my-extensionconfig
  namespace: foooo

The namespace "foooo" gets set, but this should not be done.
Related: How to call a Kustomize patch after namemspace transformation?

see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58173823/how-to-override-a-namespace-override

@jcompetence I tried that answer, but it does not help.

I don't think that's possible. They closed this some time ago https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/106 . Perhaps open a new issue?

What you want isn't currently possible.
The list of resources that Kustomize knows are cluster scoped is hard coded here. While there is a request to make this configurable at runtime, it was opened in 2018 and closed in 2020 due to lack of activity.
Fortunately, If the resource is not namespaced, then the extraneous value for metadata.namespace isn't a problem; it will simply be ignored when you create resources.

You can get what you want with a custom transformer, although this will require you to run kustomize with the --enable-alpha-plugins and --enable-exec flags.
Create (for example) `scripts/extensionconfig-remove-namespace.sh:
mkdir -p scripts
cat > scripts/extensionsconfig-remove-namespace.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
yq -y  '.items |= map(del(select(.kind == "ExtensionConfig").metadata.namespace))'
EOF
chmod 755 scripts/extensionsconfig-remove-namespace.sh

Add the transformer to your kustomization.yaml:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: foo
resources:
- extensionconfig.yaml
- service.yaml

transformers:
  - |
    kind: StripNamespaceFromExtensionConfig
    apiVersion: example.com/v1
    metadata:
      name: strip-namespace
      annotations:
        config.kubernetes.io/function: |
          exec:
            path: ./scripts/extensionconfig-remove-namespace.sh

And run kustomize like this:
kustomize build --enable-alpha-plugins --enable-exec


Is there a way to run a patch after namespace transformation was run? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79268746/how-to-call-a-kustomize-patch-after-namemspace-transformation

Transformers run after patches, so a patch cannot make the change. I mean, you could accomplish what you want with a shell pipeline, like kustomize build | yq 'select(.kind=="ExtensionConfig")|del(.metadata.namespace)' | kubectl apply -f- (that's using this yq). If you're using something like argocd, there may be options for making a filter like this part of your deployment workflow.

is it possible to create a transformer which does a patch, so that this gets called after the namespace transformer?

Sure; see my update to the answer.

This is awesome, didn't know you could do that. Is this documented anywhere?

Kustomize isn't really known for the quality of its documentation. There are some hints littered throughout the repository, like this example or this one.

@larsks thank you for that hint. BTW, any transformer does the work. A simple PatchJson6902Transformer works fine. I created an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/79296673/633961
