How to call a Kustomize patch after namespace transformation?
How to make kustomize run a patch after namespace transformation was done?
Example, to reproduce:
extensionconfig.yaml
apiVersion: runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ExtensionConfig
metadata:
  name: my-extensionconfig

kustomization.yaml
resources:
- extensionconfig.yaml

namespace: foooo

output:
❯ kubectl kustomize  .
apiVersion: runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ExtensionConfig
metadata:
  name: my-extensionconfig
  namespace: foooo

Now namespace "foooo" is set. Now I want to update this resource with the same kustomization.yaml file, and do an additional patch.
Related question: How to exclude a resource when using namespace in kustomization.yaml?

Why does it matter? You should be able to define a patch without specifying a namespace for a resource in the patch manifest and kustomize should be able to figure it out.

@Moti for me the manifest of ExtensionConfig must not have a namespace, because the Go package I use to apply the manifest will not work (because the resource is cluster-scoped). On the other hand I want to have namespace: ... because there are other resources which need the namespace transformation. NS trans works great, except there are cluster scoped CRDs. But I found a solution (see my answer below).

My answer is based on the solution of user larsks https://stackoverflow.com/a/79269650/633961
transformers are called after namespace transformers.
input: extensionconfig.yaml
apiVersion: runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ExtensionConfig
metadata:
  name: my-extensionconfig

kustomization.yaml:
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: foo
resources:
- extensionconfig.yaml

transformers:
- patch.yaml

patch.yaml
apiVersion: builtin
jsonOp: |-
  - op: remove
    path: /metadata/namespace
kind: PatchJson6902Transformer
metadata:
  name: patch6902
target:
  name: my-extensionconfig

Result:
❯ kustomize build .          

apiVersion: runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ExtensionConfig
metadata:
  name: my-extensionconfig

--> no "namespace". Problem solved, I am happy.

Good job. But I think you don't get bounty for your own answer!

To apply a patch after namespace has been added, use patchesStrategicMerge. This patch works on the already transformed resource.
Create a patch file like this
apiVersion: runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ExtensionConfig
metadata:
  name: my-extensionconfig
  namespace: foooo # Match the resource's namespace after transformation
spec:
  additionalField: new-value # Add or update a field in `spec`

and then add the patchesStrategicMerge field in your kustomization.yaml file to include the patch.
resources:
  - extensionconfig.yaml

namespace: foooo

patches:
  - target:
      kind: ExtensionConfig
      name: my-extensionconfig
      namespace: foooo # Target the resource *after* namespace is applied
    patch: |-
      - op: add
        path: /spec/additionalField
        value: new-value



Have you tried that? I get:  # Warning: 'patchesStrategicMerge' is deprecated. Please use 'patches' instead. Run 'kustomize edit fix' to update your Kustomization automatically.
Error: no matches for Id ExtensionConfig.v1alpha1.runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/my-extensionconfig.foooo; failed to find unique target for patch ExtensionConfig.v1alpha1.runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/my-extensionconfig.foooo

Afaik patchesStrategicMerge gets applied before namespace tranformation.

Yes you need to use patces now

Let me first explain how it works:

Kustomize first loads and merges your listed resources. For example, extensionconfig.yaml is taken as-is.

if you’ve specified namespace: foooo in kustomization.yaml, Kustomize will assign the foooo namespace to all namespaced resources. At this point, your ExtensionConfig now appears with namespace: foooo.

Once the resources are updated with the new namespace, Kustomize then apply patches. This means your patch file can confidently target the ExtensionConfig resource as it now stands in the foooo namespace.


Also,When you run kubectl kustomize . or kubectl apply -k ., Kustomize will:

Load extensionconfig.yaml.
Apply the namespace: foooo setting.
Merge my-patch.yaml into the now-namespaced ExtensionConfig.

Example Setup:
kustomization.yaml:
resources:
  - extensionconfig.yaml

namespace: foooo

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - my-patch.yaml


my-patch.yml
apiVersion: runtime.cluster.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ExtensionConfig
metadata:
  name: my-extensionconfig
  namespace: foooo
spec:
  extraSetting: "someValue"


The above script will load the extensionconfig.yaml and apply the namespace: foooo and then merge my-patch.yaml into the now-namespaced resource.
The final rendered output will show spec.extraSetting added to the ExtensionConfig that’s already in the foooo namespace. So Just define your patch as if the resource is already namespaced, and let Kustomize’s built-in processing order take care of the rest.

Are you sure that works? This answer uses the same approach as the one from Mayank Kumar Chaudhari. The field patchesStrategicMerge gets applied after namespace transformation. I think this answer does not solve the question.
